# listing the data from two table

Tags: sql

I have two tables staffdetails and worklog with staff's start time and finish time. I am looking for a result that lists some staff they are not started work when executing this SQL please refer below example:

staffdetails table

```
stafid  staffname
100200  John
100201  Jenny
100203  Camas
```

Worklog table

```
stfid   startime   finishtime
100200  11.30 p.m  12.30 p.m
100201  10.00 a.m  10.30 a.m
100200  12.35 p.m  12.40. p.m
100200  12.45 p.m
100203  1.30 p.m   2.30 p.m
300200  10.0 p.m   6.00 p.m
```

The output

```
staffid   stafname
100203    Camas
100201    Jenny
```

Comment: Wich RDBMS are you using, MS SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL? What have you tried? Post some working queries, does not matter if the result is incorrect, is a starting point and maybe you are not far from the solution. You can use [SQL Fiddle online tool](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3) to provide all this information.

Comment: which column tells you if a person has started his work or not? are you using start time to check? if yes & start time column is null by default then you can check if start time is null then they haven't started their work.

Comment: It seems to me you need to know what date the starttime and end time are - unless you can give a little more information n when the times get populated. What is it about Camas and Jenny that makes us think they have not started yet ? It is not clear from your example.

Comment: it looks that john has started his work but he didnt finish . so i think u looking for those who didnt finish their work. or u mean something else ?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake I made a mistake in my output it should be john instead of jenny thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  *
from    staffdetails sd
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    worklog w
        where   sd.stafid = w.stfid
                and starttime is not null
                and finishtime is null
        )
```